# R: Number of specific weekdays between two dates

Tags: r, date, weekday

I have two dates and need to know how many Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, etc. are between them, using R. Here's a pseudocode approach:

```
#PSEUDOCODE    
countwd <- function(startdate, enddate, weekday)
```

Example

```
>countwd("2014-01-01", "2014-03-30", "Monday")

[1] 13
```

Is there an existing package/function for this? If not, how could this function be set up?

Answer (score 5):

R function

```
weekdays
```

returns the weekday of a date, i.e.

```
countwd <- function(startdate, enddate, weekday){
    x <- seq( startdate, enddate, by=1 )
    y <- weekdays( x )
    sum( y == weekday )
}
```

Comment: But don't forget that the output of weekdays depends on the locale.

Comment: this works fine.  It would be interesting to see a more efficient variant that figured out the weekdays corresponding to the starting and ending days and did the appropriate (7*each weekday + number left over) calculation.

Comment: @BenBolker See my answer. You might save some microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

This follows Ben Bolker's suggestion:

```
sapply(weekdays(as.Date("2014-01-01")+1:7), function(x) countwd(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), x))
#Donnerstag    Freitag    Samstag    Sonntag     Montag   Dienstag   Mittwoch 
#        13         13         13         13         12         12         13 

countwd2 <- function(startdate, enddate, weekday){
  d <- as.integer(enddate - startdate) + 1
  d %/% 7 +
    (weekday %in% weekdays(seq(startdate, length.out=d %% 7, by=1)))
}

sapply(weekdays(as.Date("2014-01-01")+1:7), function(x) countwd2(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), x))
#Donnerstag    Freitag    Samstag    Sonntag     Montag   Dienstag   Mittwoch 
#        13         13         13         13         12         12         13 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(countwd(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), "Montag"),
               countwd2(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), "Montag"))

#Unit: microseconds
#                                                            expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# countwd(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), "Montag") 618.093 636.1095 691.7498 652.2770 682.4585 2164.709   100   b
#countwd2(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-30"), "Montag") 454.870 476.2740 504.2249 495.5215 528.9370  659.668   100  a
```

Benchmarks for a longer time period:

```
#Unit: microseconds
#                                                             expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#  countwd(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2054-03-30"), "Montag") 41384.146 42110.334 44212.9498 42896.7305 43281.538 92393.218   100
# countwd2(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2054-03-30"), "Montag")   445.323   466.265   567.4693   586.6805   652.432   822.276   100
```